# Dimension too large with a small set of data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ieeeconf

I'm trying to compile a simple tikz plot with floating point numbers, but I'm gettin a `Dimension too large` error. The tikz file works with a different data set, so I guess the problem has something to do with the data table. Any idea what is going wrong?

my .tex:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                               
\overrideIEEEmargins                                   

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\newcommand{\tsc}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}

%(...)

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \input{figs/feedback.tikz}       
    \caption{Plot of joi (Sensor \#1: CoM position along the X axis).}
    \label{fig:feedback}
\end{figure}

%(...)

\end{document}
```

my .tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 

\pgfplotstableread{
         0   -3.0631   -3.0941
    0.0080   -3.0238   -3.0590
    0.0160   -2.9845   -3.0245
    0.0240   -2.9452   -2.9900
    0.0320   -2.9060   -2.9560
    0.0400   -2.8667   -2.9225
    0.0480   -2.8274   -2.8890
    0.0560   -2.7882   -2.8559
    0.0640   -2.7489   -2.8234
    0.0720   -2.7096   -2.7906
    0.0800   -2.6704   -2.7590
    0.0880   -2.6311   -2.7271
    0.0960   -2.5918   -2.6957
    0.1040   -2.5525   -2.6645
    0.1120   -2.5133   -2.6333
    0.1200   -2.4740   -2.6032
    0.1280   -2.4347   -2.5727
    0.1360   -2.3955   -2.5431
    0.1440   -2.3562   -2.5133
    0.1520   -2.3169   -2.4829
    0.1600   -2.2777   -2.4544
    0.1680   -2.2384   -2.4247
    0.1760   -2.1991   -2.3964
    0.1840   -2.1598   -2.3661
    0.1920   -2.1206   -2.3382
    0.2000   -2.0813   -2.3100
    0.2080   -2.0420   -2.2808
    0.2160   -2.0028   -2.2534
    0.2240   -1.9635   -2.2262
    0.2320   -1.9242   -2.1977
    0.2400   -1.8850   -2.1704
    0.2480   -1.8457   -2.1239
    0.2560   -1.8064   -2.0755
    0.2640   -1.7671   -2.0273
    0.2720   -1.7279   -1.9790
    0.2800   -1.6886   -1.9306
    0.2880   -1.6493   -1.8822
    0.2960   -1.6101   -1.8338
    0.3040   -1.5708   -1.7852
    0.3120   -1.5315   -1.7366
    0.3200   -1.4923   -1.6878
    0.3280   -1.4530   -1.6390
    0.3360   -1.4137   -1.5901
    0.3440   -1.3744   -1.5411
    0.3520   -1.3352   -1.5297
    0.3600   -1.2959   -1.4981
    0.3680   -1.2566   -1.4861
    0.3760   -1.2174   -1.4532
    0.3840   -1.1781   -1.4221
    0.3920   -1.1388   -1.3911
    0.4000   -1.0996   -1.3591
    0.4080   -1.0603   -1.3280
    0.4160   -1.0210   -1.2955
    0.4240   -0.9817   -1.2654
    0.4320   -0.9425   -1.2241
    0.4400   -0.9032   -1.1789
    0.4480   -0.8639   -1.1291
    0.4560   -0.8247   -1.0793
    0.4640   -0.7854   -1.0296
    0.4720   -0.7461   -0.9801
    0.4800   -0.7069   -0.9314
    0.4880   -0.6676   -0.8859
    0.4960   -0.6283   -0.8384
    0.5040   -0.5890   -0.7921
    0.5120   -0.5498   -0.7437
    0.5200   -0.5105   -0.6955
    0.5280   -0.4712   -0.6476
    0.5360   -0.4320   -0.6000
    0.5440   -0.3927   -0.5527
    0.5520   -0.3534   -0.5058
    0.5600   -0.3142   -0.4591
    0.5680   -0.2749   -0.4129
    0.5760   -0.2356   -0.3669
    0.5840   -0.1963   -0.3214
    0.5920   -0.1571   -0.2762
    0.6000   -0.1178   -0.2314
    0.6080   -0.0785   -0.1871
    0.6160   -0.0393   -0.1431
    0.6240   -0.0000   -0.0995
    0.6320    0.0393   -0.0563
    0.6400    0.0785   -0.0135
    0.6480    0.1178    0.0289
    0.6560    0.1571    0.0709
    0.6640    0.1963    0.1125
    0.6720    0.2356    0.1537
    0.6800    0.2749    0.1945
    0.6880    0.3142    0.2349
    0.6960    0.3534    0.2749
    0.7040    0.3927    0.3145
    0.7120    0.4320    0.3537
    0.7200    0.4712    0.3924
    0.7280    0.5105    0.4309
    0.7360    0.5498    0.4689
    0.7440    0.5890    0.5066
    0.7520    0.6283    0.5439
    0.7600    0.6676    0.5809
    0.7680    0.7069    0.6175
    0.7760    0.7461    0.6538
    0.7840    0.7854    0.6897
    0.7920    0.8247    0.7253
    0.8000    0.8639    0.7606
    0.8080    0.9032    0.7956
    0.8160    0.9425    0.8302
    0.8240    0.9817    0.8645
    0.8320    1.0210    0.8985
    0.8400    1.0603    0.9323
    0.8480    1.0996    0.9657
    0.8560    1.1388    0.9988
    0.8640    1.1781    1.0317
    0.8720    1.2174    1.0643
    0.8800    1.2566    1.0966
    0.8880    1.2959    1.1286
    0.8960    1.3352    1.2115
    0.9040    1.3744    1.2576
    0.9120    1.4137    1.3059
    0.9200    1.4530    1.3546
    0.9280    1.4923    1.4034
    0.9360    1.5315    1.4529
    0.9440    1.5708    1.5028
    0.9520    1.6101    1.5533
    0.9600    1.6493    1.6040
    0.9680    1.6886    1.6541
    0.9760    1.7279    1.7040
    0.9840    1.7671    1.7537
    0.9920    1.8064    1.8038
    1.0000    1.8457    1.8530
    1.0080    1.8850    1.8824
    1.0160    1.9242    1.9109
    1.0240    1.9635    1.9386
    1.0320    2.0028    1.9667
    1.0400    2.0420    1.9949
    1.0480    2.0813    2.0234
    1.0560    2.1206    2.0520
    1.0640    2.1598    2.0809
    1.0720    2.1991    2.1311
    1.0800    2.2384    2.1784
    1.0880    2.2777    2.2215
    1.0960    2.3169    2.2675
    1.1040    2.3562    2.3130
    1.1120    2.3955    2.3575
    1.1200    2.4347    2.3999
    1.1280    2.4740    2.4464
    1.1360    2.5133    2.4893
    1.1440    2.5525    2.5324
    1.1520    2.5918    2.5761
    1.1600    2.6311    2.6187
    1.1680    2.6704    2.6604
    1.1760    2.7096    2.7025
    1.1840    2.7489    2.7432
    1.1920    2.7882    2.7839
    1.2000    2.8274    2.8240
    1.2080    2.8667    2.8638
    1.2160    2.9060    2.9024
    1.2240    2.9452    2.9418
    1.2320    2.9845    2.9796
    1.2400    3.0238    3.0170
    1.2480    3.0631    3.0545
    1.2560    3.1023    3.0914
    1.2640    3.1416    3.1276
    1.2720    3.1809    3.1635
    1.2800   -3.0631   -3.0842
    1.2880   -3.0238   -3.0493
    1.2960   -2.9845   -3.0149
    1.3040   -2.9452   -2.9804
    1.3120   -2.9060   -2.9470
    1.3200   -2.8667   -2.9133
    1.3280   -2.8274   -2.8800
    1.3360   -2.7882   -2.8472
    1.3440   -2.7489   -2.8145
    1.3520   -2.7096   -2.7825
    1.3600   -2.6704   -2.7502
    1.3680   -2.6311   -2.7186
    1.3760   -2.5918   -2.6868
    1.3840   -2.5525   -2.6558
    1.3920   -2.5133   -2.6255
    1.4000   -2.4740   -2.5947
    1.4080   -2.4347   -2.5646
    1.4160   -2.3955   -2.5347
    1.4240   -2.3562   -2.5045
    1.4320   -2.3169   -2.4755
    1.4400   -2.2777   -2.4454
    1.4480   -2.2384   -2.4160
    1.4560   -2.1991   -2.3874
    1.4640   -2.1598   -2.3591
    1.4720   -2.1206   -2.3303
    1.4800   -2.0813   -2.3026
    1.4880   -2.0420   -2.2741
    1.4960   -2.0028   -2.2463
    1.5040   -1.9635   -2.2177
    1.5120   -1.9242   -2.1889
    1.5200   -1.8850   -2.1614
    1.5280   -1.8457   -2.1149
    1.5360   -1.8064   -2.0669
    1.5440   -1.7671   -2.0187
    1.5520   -1.7279   -1.9703
    1.5600   -1.6886   -1.9219
    1.5680   -1.6493   -1.8734
    1.5760   -1.6101   -1.8249
    1.5840   -1.5708   -1.7763
    1.5920   -1.5315   -1.7275
    1.6000   -1.4923   -1.6786
    1.6080   -1.4530   -1.6297
    1.6160   -1.4137   -1.5807
    1.6240   -1.3744   -1.5317
    1.6320   -1.3352   -1.5193
    1.6400   -1.2959   -1.4903
    1.6480   -1.2566   -1.4722
    1.6560   -1.2174   -1.4420
    1.6640   -1.1781   -1.4105
    1.6720   -1.1388   -1.3797
    1.6800   -1.0996   -1.3495
    1.6880   -1.0603   -1.3199
    1.6960   -1.0210   -1.2904
    1.7040   -0.9817   -1.2594
    1.7120   -0.9425   -1.2290
    1.7200   -0.9032   -1.1989
    1.7280   -0.8639   -1.1542
    1.7360   -0.8247   -1.1136
    1.7440   -0.7854   -1.0677
    1.7520   -0.7461   -1.0180
    1.7600   -0.7069   -0.9685
    1.7680   -0.6676   -0.9192
    1.7760   -0.6283   -0.8701
    1.7840   -0.5890   -0.8213
    1.7920   -0.5498   -0.7726
    1.8000   -0.5105   -0.7242
    1.8080   -0.4712   -0.6761
    1.8160   -0.4320   -0.6283
    1.8240   -0.3927   -0.5807
    1.8320   -0.3534   -0.5335
    1.8400   -0.3142   -0.4866
    1.8480   -0.2749   -0.4401
    1.8560   -0.2356   -0.3940
    1.8640   -0.1963   -0.3482
    1.8720   -0.1571   -0.3028
    1.8800   -0.1178   -0.2578
    1.8880   -0.0785   -0.2131
    1.8960   -0.0393   -0.1689
    1.9040   -0.0000   -0.1250
    1.9120    0.0393   -0.0816
    1.9200    0.0785   -0.0385
    1.9280    0.1178    0.0041
    1.9360    0.1571    0.0464
    1.9440    0.1963    0.0882
    1.9520    0.2356    0.1296
    1.9600    0.2749    0.1706
    1.9680    0.3142    0.2112
    1.9760    0.3534    0.2515
    1.9840    0.3927    0.2913
    1.9920    0.4320    0.3307
    2.0000    0.4712    0.3698
    2.0080    0.5105    0.4084
    2.0160    0.5498    0.4467
    2.0240    0.5890    0.4846
    2.0320    0.6283    0.5222
    2.0400    0.6676    0.5594
    2.0480    0.7069    0.5962
    2.0560    0.7461    0.6327
    2.0640    0.7854    0.6688
    2.0720    0.8247    0.7046
    2.0800    0.8639    0.7400
    2.0880    0.9032    0.7751
    2.0960    0.9425    0.8100
    2.1040    0.9817    0.8444
    2.1120    1.0210    0.8786
    2.1200    1.0603    0.9124
    2.1280    1.0996    0.9460
    2.1360    1.1388    0.9792
    2.1440    1.1781    1.0122
    2.1520    1.2174    1.0449
    2.1600    1.2566    1.0773
    2.1680    1.2959    1.1095
    2.1760    1.3352    1.1909
    2.1840    1.3744    1.2368
    2.1920    1.4137    1.2851
    2.2000    1.4530    1.3331
    2.2080    1.4923    1.3828
    2.2160    1.5315    1.4327
    2.2240    1.5708    1.4829
    2.2320    1.6101    1.5331
    2.2400    1.6493    1.5834
    2.2480    1.6886    1.6339
    2.2560    1.7279    1.6842
    2.2640    1.7671    1.7342
    2.2720    1.8064    1.7839
    2.2800    1.8457    1.8335
    2.2880    1.8850    1.8629
    2.2960    1.9242    1.8913
    2.3040    1.9635    1.9198
    2.3120    2.0028    1.9474
    2.3200    2.0420    1.9753
    2.3280    2.0813    2.0036
    2.3360    2.1206    2.0319
    2.3440    2.1598    2.0605
    2.3520    2.1991    2.0893
    2.3600    2.2384    2.1181
    2.3680    2.2777    2.1470
    2.3760    2.3169    2.1759
    2.3840    2.3562    2.2331
    2.3920    2.3955    2.2718
    2.4000    2.4347    2.3168
    2.4080    2.4740    2.3614
    2.4160    2.5133    2.4079
    2.4240    2.5525    2.4517
    2.4320    2.5918    2.4972
    2.4400    2.6311    2.5420
    2.4480    2.6704    2.5848
    2.4560    2.7096    2.6288
    2.4640    2.7489    2.6711
    2.4720    2.7882    2.7128
    2.4800    2.8274    2.7542
    2.4880    2.8667    2.7947
    2.4960    2.9060    2.8343
    2.5040    2.9452    2.8734
    2.5120    2.9845    2.9128
    2.5200    3.0238    2.9517
    2.5280    3.0631    2.9893
    2.5360    3.1023    3.0269
    2.5440    3.1416    3.0635
    2.5520    3.1809    3.1001
    2.5600   -3.0631    3.1361
    2.5680   -3.0238    3.1718
    2.5760   -2.9845   -3.0761
    2.5840   -2.9452   -3.0411
    2.5920   -2.9060   -3.0068
    2.6000   -2.8667   -2.9725
    2.6080   -2.8274   -2.9386
    2.6160   -2.7882   -2.9054
    2.6240   -2.7489   -2.8723
    2.6320   -2.7096   -2.8395
    2.6400   -2.6704   -2.8072
    2.6480   -2.6311   -2.7748
    2.6560   -2.5918   -2.7431
    2.6640   -2.5525   -2.7116
    2.6720   -2.5133   -2.6804
    2.6800   -2.4740   -2.6491
    2.6880   -2.4347   -2.6184
    2.6960   -2.3955   -2.5882
    2.7040   -2.3562   -2.5577
    2.7120   -2.3169   -2.5275
    2.7200   -2.2777   -2.4983
    2.7280   -2.2384   -2.4689
    2.7360   -2.1991   -2.4406
    2.7440   -2.1598   -2.4108
    2.7520   -2.1206   -2.3816
    2.7600   -2.0813   -2.3536
    2.7680   -2.0420   -2.3246
    2.7760   -2.0028   -2.2965
    2.7840   -1.9635   -2.2689
    2.7920   -1.9242   -2.2401
    2.8000   -1.8850   -2.2130
    2.8080   -1.8457   -2.1668
    2.8160   -1.8064   -2.1191
    2.8240   -1.7671   -2.0714
    2.8320   -1.7279   -2.0237
    2.8400   -1.6886   -1.9755
    2.8480   -1.6493   -1.9273
    2.8560   -1.6101   -1.8791
    2.8640   -1.5708   -1.8307
    2.8720   -1.5315   -1.7822
    2.8800   -1.4923   -1.7336
    2.8880   -1.4530   -1.6849
    2.8960   -1.4137   -1.6361
    2.9040   -1.3744   -1.5872
    2.9120   -1.3352   -1.5770
    2.9200   -1.2959   -1.5465
    2.9280   -1.2566   -1.5184
    2.9360   -1.2174   -1.4906
    2.9440   -1.1781   -1.4621
    2.9520   -1.1388   -1.4425
    2.9600   -1.0996   -1.4115
    2.9680   -1.0603   -1.3821
    2.9760   -1.0210   -1.3508
    2.9840   -0.9817   -1.3200
    2.9920   -0.9425   -1.2897
    3.0000   -0.9032   -1.2600
    3.0080   -0.8639   -1.2299
    3.0160   -0.8247   -1.1991
    3.0240   -0.7854   -1.1683
    3.0320   -0.7461   -1.1382
    3.0400   -0.7069   -1.0942
    3.0480   -0.6676   -1.0554
    3.0560   -0.6283   -1.0138
    3.0640   -0.5890   -0.9646
    3.0720   -0.5498   -0.9182
    3.0800   -0.5105   -0.8690
    3.0880   -0.4712   -0.8201
    3.0960   -0.4320   -0.7714
    3.1040   -0.3927   -0.7230
    3.1120   -0.3534   -0.6748
    3.1200   -0.3142   -0.6270
    3.1280   -0.2749   -0.5795
    3.1360   -0.2356   -0.5322
    3.1440   -0.1963   -0.4854
    3.1520   -0.1571   -0.4388
    3.1600   -0.1178   -0.3927
    3.1680   -0.0785   -0.3468
    3.1760   -0.0393   -0.3014
    3.1840   -0.0000   -0.2563
    3.1920    0.0393   -0.2117
    3.2000    0.0785   -0.1674
    3.2080    0.1178   -0.1235
    3.2160    0.1571   -0.0801
    3.2240    0.1963   -0.0370
    3.2320    0.2356    0.0056
    3.2400    0.2749    0.0479
    3.2480    0.3142    0.0897
    3.2560    0.3534    0.1311
    3.2640    0.3927    0.1722
    3.2720    0.4320    0.2128
    3.2800    0.4712    0.2529
    3.2880    0.5105    0.2928
    3.2960    0.5498    0.3322
    3.3040    0.5890    0.3712
    3.3120    0.6283    0.4099
    3.3200    0.6676    0.4482
    3.3280    0.7069    0.4861
    3.3360    0.7461    0.5236
    3.3440    0.7854    0.5609
    3.3520    0.8247    0.5977
    3.3600    0.8639    0.6342
    3.3680    0.9032    0.6703
    3.3760    0.9425    0.7060
    3.3840    0.9817    0.7414
    3.3920    1.0210    0.7765
    3.4000    1.0603    0.8113
    3.4080    1.0996    0.8457
    3.4160    1.1388    0.8799
    3.4240    1.1781    0.9138
    3.4320    1.2174    0.9472
    3.4400    1.2566    0.9805
    3.4480    1.2959    1.0135
    3.4560    1.3352    1.0462
    3.4640    1.3744    1.1214
    3.4720    1.4137    1.1685
    3.4800    1.4530    1.2160
    3.4880    1.4923    1.2639
    3.4960    1.5315    1.3194
    3.5040    1.5708    1.3693
    3.5120    1.6101    1.4188
    3.5200    1.6493    1.4688
    3.5280    1.6886    1.5202
    3.5360    1.7279    1.5707
    3.5440    1.7671    1.6208
    3.5520    1.8064    1.6711
    3.5600    1.8457    1.7209
    3.5680    1.8850    1.7506
    3.5760    1.9242    1.7783
    3.5840    1.9635    1.8065
    3.5920    2.0028    1.8348
    3.6000    2.0420    1.8632
    3.6080    2.0813    1.8916
    3.6160    2.1206    1.9201
    3.6240    2.1598    1.9486
    3.6320    2.1991    1.9772
    3.6400    2.2384    2.0058
    3.6480    2.2777    2.0344
    3.6560    2.3169    2.0631
    3.6640    2.3562    2.1092
    3.6720    2.3955    2.1531
    3.6800    2.4347    2.1962
    3.6880    2.4740    2.2423
    3.6960    2.5133    2.2826
    3.7040    2.5525    2.3276
    3.7120    2.5918    2.3713
    3.7200    2.6311    2.4121
    3.7280    2.6704    2.4555
    3.7360    2.7096    2.5003
    3.7440    2.7489    2.5442
    3.7520    2.7882    2.5884
    3.7600    2.8274    2.6314
    3.7680    2.8667    2.6744
    3.7760    2.9060    2.7157
    3.7840    2.9452    2.7560
    3.7920    2.9845    2.7970
    3.8000    3.0238    2.8362
    3.8080    3.0631    2.8760
    3.8160    3.1023    2.9147
    3.8240    3.1416    2.9529
    3.8320    3.1809    2.9908
    3.8400   -3.0631    3.0285
    3.8480   -3.0238    3.0654
    3.8560   -2.9845    3.1019
    3.8640   -2.9452    3.1381
    3.8720   -2.9060    3.1738
    3.8800   -2.8667   -3.0741
    3.8880   -2.8274   -3.0391
    3.8960   -2.7882   -3.0049
    3.9040   -2.7489   -2.9707
    3.9120   -2.7096   -2.9367
    3.9200   -2.6704   -2.9039
    3.9280   -2.6311   -2.8706
    3.9360   -2.5918   -2.8379
    3.9440   -2.5525   -2.8053
    3.9520   -2.5133   -2.7732
    3.9600   -2.4740   -2.7411
    3.9680   -2.4347   -2.7098
    3.9760   -2.3955   -2.6784
    3.9840   -2.3562   -2.6473
    3.9920   -2.3169   -2.6165
}\data

\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
ymin=-3.5,
ymax=3.5,
xlabel near ticks,
ylabel near ticks,
]

\addplot [black,dashed, opacity=0.5] table [y expr=\thisrow{1}] {\data};
\addplot [red, line width=1pt] table [y expr=\thisrow{2}] {\data};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I don't have the `ieeconf` document class, but using `article` and commenting out the lines `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                          
\overrideIEEEmargins` I get the image with no problems. Do you get the image making those same changes or do you still get the error message?

Comment: Yes, even without those lines I get the error...

Comment: @joaocandre have you solved this? I suspect that updating your packages will take care of it.